# input() Statement Constantly Raising TypeError

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have made a class which uses a few methods/functions(I don't know what to call them) from the `Image` module in the `PIL library`. In this code, I am asking the user to enter a new height for the image to be resized to. Since I want the user to enter it again if an error is raised, I have it in a `while` loop.

I was initially trying to accept a tuple instead and then unpack it into the new_height and new_width variables but I figured it might confuse the user.

Please assume that all the imports have been made.

```
class ImageManip:

def __init__(self):
    self.img_width, self.img_height = self.img.size

    self.img_resize()

def img_resize(self):
    while True:
        clear()
        try:
            img_new_width = input(
                '\n\nYour image\'s dimensions are:' +
                '\nWidth: ' + self.img_width +
                '\nHeight: ' + self.img_height +
                '\n\nEnter the width: '
            )

            img_new_height = input(
                'Enter the height: '
            )
        except TypeError:
            print('Oh no! You didn\'t enter a number! Try again.')
            time.sleep(2)
            print('\n\n', end='')
            continue
        else:
            self.img_final = self.img.thumbnail((img_new_width, img_new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.img_final.show()
            break
```

`System: Windows 10, 32bit
Version: Python 3.6`

Comment: cast it into int: `int(input("....."))`

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input()` needs to be called with a string. `self.img_height` and `self.img_width` are integers in your code. 
If you call `str()` on these to convert them to strings, it should work:

```
 img_new_width = input(
            '\n\nYour image\'s dimensions are:' +
            '\nWidth: ' + str(self.img_width) +
            '\nHeight: ' + str(self.img_height) +
            '\n\nEnter the width: '
        )
```

You probably want to convert the input to an integer using `int()` as well:

```
img_new_width = int(input(
           ...
        )
```